# Dynamically create and delete multiple text fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the "nested_form" gem to build my complex Rails form.

In that I need to delete or add multiple rows like:

```
1. name  textbox  purpose textbox description textarea
2. name  textbox  purpose textbox description textarea
.
.
and so on..
```

I can delete or add one name field at a time, but I need to create three of above fields at the same time.
I went through Railscast 197 too but that didn't help much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails' nested attributes instead of using any gem.

Suppose you have a model called `Company`, where Company can have many Employees:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees
end
```

Your Company form will be something like:

```
<%= form_for(@company, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
    <a href="#">Add Employee</a>
    <div class="employees"></div> <!-- Append the HTML template for employees (controller with JS) -->
<% end %>
```

Your HTML template for Employee will be something like:

```
<div class="field more_cancer_types" class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "company[employees_attributes][][id]", nil %>
    <%= text_field_tag "company[employees_attributes][][name]", nil, :placeholder=> " - Add Employee - " %>
    <a class="remove_field" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove</a>
</div>
```

And, with JavaScript, you can add or delete this template.

Comment: Dont worry rails will take care of it (will prepare an array of employees attributes with each entity separated), make sure to pass `nil` if a checkbox is not selected.